# Let $f\in C([a,b])$ and $\int_{a}^{x}f=\int_{x}^{b}f \ \forall x\in[a,b]$. Show that $f=0$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, derivatives

> Let $f\in C([a,b])$ and $\int_{a}^{x}f=\int_{x}^{b}f \ \forall x\in[a,b]$. Show that $f=0$ on $[a,b]$. I would like to know if my proof holds, please. My attempt is to pass by primitive of $f$.

As $f\in C([a,b])$, then it has a primitive such that $F'(x)=f$. Moreover, as $$\int_{a}^{x}f=\int_{x}^{b}f \ \forall x\in[a,b]$$ we have the following:

$$F(x)-F(a)=F(b)-F(x) \iff F(x)=\frac{F(b)+F(a)}{2}.$$

The previous equality holds $\forall x \in[a,b]$. Therefore $F$ is constant $\implies$ $f=0$ (as $F'(x)=f(x)$).

Comment: Your proof is fine. Also $F'(x)=f$ should be written as $F'=f$ (or $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$).

Comment: It is correct, just replace "inequality" by "equality."

Comment: Thank you all for your feedbacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It works even in the case that $f$ is “only” Lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$, in that case the conclusion is that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere on $[a, b]$.

As an alternative one can observe that the integral vanishes over all subintervals $[c,d]\subset [a, b]$:
$$ 
\int_c^d f(x) \, dx = \int_a^d f(x) \, dx - \int_a^c f(x) \, dx \\
= \int_d^b f(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx = -\int_c^d f(x) \, dx
$$
implies
$$
\int_c^d f(x) \, dx = 0 \, .
$$
If $f$ is continuous and not identically zero then it is strictly positive or strictly negative on some subinterval, and that gives a contradiction.